# Open dialog maximized error at angular 6 with primeng

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using Angular 6 with PrimeNg. I want to open dialog as maximized. I can doing this by below code . But in `toggleMaximize` method, it gave me this error: **event.preventdefault is not a function**. What can be the reason of this error.

```
    <p-dialog #dialStudent (onShow)="showDialogMaximized($event,dialStudent)" [(visible)]="displayDialog">
        asdfgh
    </p-dialog>
```

.ts file

```
showDialogMaximized(event, dialog: Dialog) {
    dialog.maximized = false;
    dialog.toggleMaximize(event);
  }
```

primeNg toggleMaximize method

```
Dialog.prototype.toggleMaximize = function (event) {
        if (this.maximized)
            this.revertMaximize();
        else
            this.maximize();
        event.preventDefault();
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. We should use `maximize` method instead of `toggleMaximize` method. And we must use with setTimeout. If we don't use setTimeout, then autoHeight of dialog don't working properly.

```
  showDialogMaximized(dialog: Dialog) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dialog.maximize();
    }, 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//in p-dialog
[(visible)]="display" 

showDialog() {
    this.display = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        const ele: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('pi-window-maximize')[0] as HTMLElement;
        setTimeout(() => {
            ele.click();
        }, 0);
    }, 0);
}
```

Call the function above on click of any button